# Windows phone apps with same GUID - Creating more apps from one single app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

I had made a Windows Phone 7 application. I copy pasted that same application 10 times to create 10 different applications, as the only difference in those 10 apps were the images. But now I cannot install 2 applications on emulator as they have same GUID. I tried using the **GUID generator tool** and replaced the **product id** in **WMAppManifest.xml** file and also the **GUID** in **Assembly Information** with the **new generated GUID**, but as soon as I **Rebuild** the solution, it goes back to the same old GUID and still replaces other app already installed with same GUID. Can anyone help me why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you done a search of the old GUID string to find out where else it might be defined?

Comment: AFAIK, it is there in the Assembly Info and WMAppManifest.xml file. Also a strange thing I noticed was the GUID and product ID in the XML file were different.

Comment: Sick people just trying to downvote! Maybe the problem never occurred for you, but I am GENUINELY STUCK !

Comment: They probably downvoted because they thought the question wasn't complete. Kind of rude to do that though without offering a suggestion on how to make it better.

Comment: I have tried making the question as complete as possible. I don't think I missed out anything from the XML file to Assembly Info, nothing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I got it working finally!!** It might help somebody who might be stuck just like me.

The mistake I was doing was I was entering the GUID generated by the tool in **UpperCase** while it has to be put in "LowerCase". The GUID Generator tool in Visual Studio 2012 generates a GUID something like this: "**AAB123-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx**" while what the WMAppManifest.xml file takes is: "**aab123-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx**".

So the steps to change GUID of any project is as follows:

1. Go to [www.guidgen.com](http://www.guidgen.com)
2. Copy the GUID.
3. Open Assembly Information and paste it in the GUID field (**in lowercase only**).
4. Open WMAppManifest.xml file and paste it again in the **productID** field (**again in lowercase only**)
5. Rebuild and deploy the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the GUID issue copy the projects following next steps:

1. Copy the project folder
2. Change the name to the .csproj file
3. Add the copyed project to the solution: *Right click on solution* -> *Add* -> *Existing
   project...*
4. Open the WMAppManifest.xml file and replace the Product ID (you can use a generator)

This works for me. If I deploy multiple projects to the phone I can see all of them ther, they're not replaced.

Comment: I got it working without adding it as a solution to existing project.

Comment: @rishiJasapara how you differentiated both projects?