# How to differentiate two projects in a single solution in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Iin my visual studio express, i have two projects in a single solution.
What i want to know is that how can i differentiate both the projects??

FYI - I have added the seond project by the steps given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686361/windows-phone-apps-with-same-guid-creating-more-apps-from-one-single-app)

Comment: What do you mean by differenciate? Can't you already differentiate them by their names?

Comment: how to use conditional compilation guards around the code? If my first project is A and second one is B. How can i use conditional compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question. If I understood well you just need to add reference to the projects from your main project and you can use resources from them.

Can you please provide more info about what you really need?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use conditional compilation:

Set a conditional compilation symbol on each project (go to the project settings, "build" tab). For example add the compilation symbol "APP1".

Then in your code, use the following syntax:

```
#if APP1
// This is APP1 code
#endif
```

Comment: I'm using Visual studio express 2012 for windows phone. Here how can i add compilation symbol?

Comment: Right click on the project -> Properties -> Build tab